# Cucumber regex step definition

Tags: cucumber, bdd

Can someone explain what is the difference between

```
@When("some text (.*)")
```

and

```
@When("^some text ([^\"]*)$")
```

?

The former worked when using a straightforward step, but when using a data table it maps only to the first table item.

Comment: How are you using the two different steps in the feature file?

Comment: And can you post the method signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is explanation of couple of common regex :

**.***  matches anything (or nothing), literally “any character (except a newline) 0 or more times”

**.+**  matches at least one of anything

**[0-9]** or d matches a series of digits (or nothing)

**[0-9]+** or **d+**    matches one or more digits

**"[^"]*"** matches something (or nothing) in double quotes

**an?** matches a or an (the question mark makes the n optional)

**So, depending on your question, the difference is :**

.* will take everything except the new lines, 
([^\"]*) this will take everything also the new lines