# Regular expression in gluecode skipping skipping 'en' word

Tags: regex, groovy, cucumber, katalon-studio

I have a gluecode for Cucumber, and the correct string is not being parsed when string 'publiceren' = ' Intern en Extern':

```
@En('^de vacature betreft een (.*) voor (.*) en heeft de volgende gegevens: (.*), (.*), (.*), (.*), (.*) en (.*?)$')
    def de_vacature_betreft_een_vacaturetype_voor_medewerker(String vacaturetype, String medewerker, String recruiter, String uren, String werkervaring, String opleiding, String achtergrond, String publiceren) {

        println(publiceren) 
    }
```

The result i get is just 'Extern', where the problem seems to be the 'en' part of the string.
How can i solve this? Additionally, is this approach even correct with all the (.*)'s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default regex is greedy so the capture group for `achtergrond` will contain `...'publiceren' = ' Intern`. You either have to add delimiters (i.e. `"`) around your step arguments and exclude these from capture `"([^"]*)"` or make the second to last capture group non greedy i.e. `(.*?)`.

Comment: Thanks! This works!  New gluecode now is:  

@En('^de vacature betreft een (.*) voor (.*) en heeft de volgende gegevens: (.*), (.*), (.*), (.*), (.*?) en (.*)$')

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819414/cucumber-regex-step-definition), `.*` will take everything except the new lines, `([^\"]*)` this will take everything including the new lines. So, try with `([^\"]*)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is not helping with the issue. I still get 'Extern' as output, instead of the expected 'Intern en Extern'

Comment: Can you post the output, along with the text the step maps to?

Comment: Just to confirm, do i have to use your suggestion only on the last part or replace every (.*)?

Comment: You can try both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@En('de vacature betreft een (.*) voor (.*) en heeft de volgende gegevens: (.*), (.*), (.*), (.*), (.*) en (.*)')
def de_vacature_betreft_een_vacaturetype_voor_medewerker(String vacaturetype, String medewerker, String recruiter, String uren, String werkervaring, String opleiding, String achtergrond, String publiceren) {
    println(publiceren) 
}
```

Comment: Using this unfortunately doesnt change anything, the result is now "Extern"